# change flot pie chart font size

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to increase the label font size in a piece of existing code. I know it should be through the Label Formatter but for the life of me can't fathom how to do it.
Existing code

```
....
label: {
     show: true,
     radius 3/4,
     formatter: labelFormatter,
     background: {
          opacity: 0.0
          color: '#000'
     }
 }
 .......
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom function as your label formater and change font size there with CSS like this:

```
....
label: {
     show: true,
     radius 3/4,
     formatter: labelFormatter,
     background: {
          opacity: 0.0
          color: '#000'
     }
 }
 .......

function labelFormatter(label, series) {
    return "<span style='font-size:10px'>"+label+" "+series+"</span>";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that solves an issue but label simply displays the label title and not the series value. I have replaced label with series.data and get the value but preceded with "1," ie "1, 9" where 9 is the value.

Comment: Not a problem. Please mark my answer as correct solution. Thanks! I have also adjusted response so it displayed label and series.